# Expression for Markov Kernel sampling indeces in $\{0, \ldots, T\}$ according to weights depending on another variable

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability, markov-chain-montecarlo, measure-theory

I have a vector $x = (x_0, \ldots, x_T)$ and given this vector, I would like to sample an index $k$ between $0$ and $T$. The probability of sampling index $k$ is given by a weight $w_k$ that is a function of $x_k$. In other words
$$
\mathbb{P}(\mathsf{k} = k \mid x) = w_k,
$$
where $w_k = w_k(x_k)$. I will assume these weights sum up to one $\sum_{k=0}^T w_k = 1$. Basically this is a Categorical distribution conditioned on $x$. I would like to write a measure-theoretic expression for the Markov Kernel corresponding to this operation.

> Note: I understand that this is a discrete sampling procedure, but I am trying to understand measure theory better. I have a decent understanding of the theory of Markov Kernels, but I am struggling to construct a Markov Kernel given a practical sampling procedure. This is basically for me to see how one would go about writing the expression for the kernel.

## Attempt

I am looking to write down something (even if pseudo-correctly) as $K(x, dk)$. I understand that $dk$ makes no sense in a discrete setting. Would the kernel be this?
$$
K(x, dk) = \sum_{k\in dk} w_k
$$
I basically want to go from the definition of a Markov Kernel (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_kernel) to a practical expression.